# (".menu") or ("menu") JQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've just started learning JQuery/JavaScript and I can't figure out the difference between using (".menu") and ("menu") and where I should use them?

Comment: `.menu` would select all elements with `class="menu"` (class is donated by the period at the start of the selector), `menu` would select all `<menu>` elements, you should take a look at [basic css selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/)

Comment: You might want to take a peek at this [CSS selectors reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-selectors.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is `menue`, jquery uses css selectors to select elements. `.menu` means select all elements that have a class `.menu` ans `$('menu')` means that select element with a tag `menu` which I don't know about but can be `div, p, body etc`.

Comment: You can define the html object as any tagName. even <Zohaib>

Comment: I know much JS but not too much html, It's new for me that we can define custom tags. I know we can create custom directives in Angular but don't know about  simple js or html. Thanks for info, I'll look into that.

Comment: I this answer was helpful, can you mark it as best answer because there is no other answer... Sorry for shameless favor .. :)